# retrieve specific text from batch command output

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to retrieve the version of my Mcafee DLP using a batch script.

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\McAfee\DLP\Agent"
```

The above command gives the following output:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\McAfee\DLP\Agent
    UNRSKIP    REG_SZ    skip
    AgentVersion    REG_SZ    10.0.100.372
    PackageType    REG_SZ    DLP
    CommonAppDataFolder    REG_SZ    C:\ProgramData\
```

How do i retrieve this line : AgentVersion    REG_SZ    10.0.100.372

Comment: Parse the output string for line starting with "AgentVersion"

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: I am no expert on batch script. Try googling 1. how you can get the output into a string, 2. how to parse the string using new line, 3. check the new lines with substring continuing "AgentVersion" on starting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\McAfee\DLP\Agent" | find "AgentVersion" > tmp.txt
for /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%f in (tmp.txt) do (echo %%f)
```

hope this helps !

Comment: Also, how do i add a new line as a delimiter?

Comment: You are welcome. reg. your question, am not getting it.
The for statement itself parses through all lines in the file one by one.